# Mac OS X <Option>-d keybinding

Tags: macos

When I press -d key in Mac OS X, the current application loses focus. And press it again, the current window gets focus. it's weird.

How do I know which application bind that or how to avoid it. I check the shortcuts in the system preferences and there isn't something like Option-d keybinding.

System version:

`ProductName:  Mac OS X
ProductVersion: 10.11.4
BuildVersion:   15E65`

This annoys me so much.

Thank you so much.

Comment: That's a weird way to specify your OS X version...

Comment: @Thilo Sorry, I changed it. ;-)

Comment: You may have better luck over at apple.stackexchange.com

Comment: @Thilo Thank you I will post my problem there.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

create a new user and login as that new user to see whether it works normally.

In my case, it works normally. Then check login items of the current user: Preferences > Users & Groups > Login items. Then remove unuseful items and relogin, remember to uncheck `reopen windows when relogin`.

Then, everything works normally. Thanks Nunzy in #MacOSX channel!

Thank you so much!!!